# Can I have an operating system on a USB that will boot up only when the USB is connected?

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, grub

I have a shared laptop, that I also use for my college. By default there is a W10 OS installed and used, but when I plug in USB with Ubuntu OS, I would like to have the Ubuntu boot up and use. I know I can use GRUB for dual booting, but there has been some issues with Ubuntu OS.

I have also set up boot priority for USB, and when I had USB plugged in, Windows loaded up.
UEFI is set up as well.

Anyone have an idea how to do this? And is this even possible?

Comment: how did you create your usb install? are you sure its bootable? it sounds like you have never successfully booted from it.

Comment: Is the boot USB created for UEFI boot? Is the computer BIOS/UEFI set for Secure Boot?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want your session to *persist*, so you can, for example, save documents, email, etc. to the USB, and install programs that will be available the next time you boot from it?

If that is the case, you need to [create a *persistent image* on the USB with storage space](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/). **Caveat:** Ordinary flash USB storage is *much* slower than running from a hard disk drive, much less SSD. Use the fastest drive feasible, perhaps a small external SSD, to avoid that issue.

The steps suggested by [iTecTec](https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb/) require two USB drives, if you do not have a working Ubuntu installation. Basically,

- [Install Ubuntu live](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started) on **two** USB drives.
- Boot Ubuntu from one of the USB drives,
- Run *GParted* to modify the second drive to add persistence.

This is [also readily done from Windows](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/08/rufus-creating-persistent-storage-live.html) using [Rufus](https://github.com/pbatard/rufus), which I find easier yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can always enter the boot menu during POST by pressing one of the F-keys, usually F9 - F12. That’ll allow you to choose where you want to boot from. You can also go in the BIOS and change the boot order so that USB is always tried first. If that doesn’t work, F-key always will.